# Fixing awkward gap between drywall and brick

Tags: drywall, brick

I installed this L channel on the drywall as tight as I could but the brick is so wavy I'm left with this awkward gap. What's the solution to fill this? Scribing the drywall isn't something I want to do. Am I stick cutting out these bricks and putting them in flush?

[image]

Comment: It would help if we could see what we're looking at. Is that a fireplace or what? What else exists nearby for trim? What room is this?

Comment: What the heck, I swear the original image was a view of the thing as a whole. It's an old coal chimney that comes through our kitchen. It used to be covered in plaster and now my wife wanted to expose it.

Comment: I read that the foam is against code for chimneys and flammable. Someone might try to use the chimney someday and that may cause the house to burn down.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a grout bag and fill it with mortar. Squeeze the grout into the area between the metal corner and the brick.  Making sure the gap is full an level. Let it dry to a point where you can scratch the joint with a stick or tool that has the finish that you like.

Comment: I'd paint first, but yeah.

Comment: This would only work for small gaps. We don't know how deep those holes are. You also have to take into consideration movement. Grout will crack.

Answer (score 0):

I would fill the gaps with spray foam about 3/4 the way, let it expand and dry and then then go back with drywall mud and fill the remaining void. If any of the spray foam comes out, cut it out a bit so you have a place for the mud to fill.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The only concern would be that the white from the drywall mud would contrast too much. But maybe it gets painted later...

Comment: Yeah, it would get painted at the same time and color as the wall so it looks like the wall seamlessly follows the edge of the brick.

Comment: Essentially, you're using the foam as a backer for the plaster/mortar/whatever. Yeah, should work, though you may need to carve excess foam backm